Passing classes and methods as Value with GraalVM Polyglot
I'm trying to use the Polyglot API of GraalVM, and an example I see in the documentation does not work.
The documentation of Context.asValue states:

When Java host objects are passed to guest languages, their public
methods and fields are provided as members.

And a code example is provided:
class JavaRecord {
  public int x = 42;
  public double y = 42.0;
  public String name() {
    return "foo";
  }
}
Context context = Context.create();
Value record = context.asValue(new JavaRecord());
assert record.getMember("x").asInt() == 42;
...

However this code doesn't work for me. record.getMember("x") returns null. record.getMemberKeys also returns just an empty list ([]).
The same thing happens for another example, this time passing a method to Context.asValue. The documentation states:

And single method interfaces annotated with FunctionalInterface are executable directly.

Illustrating with the example:
Context context = Context.create();
...
assert context.asValue((Supplier<Integer>) () -> 42).execute().asInt() == 42;

But when I run this example myself, I get UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation Value.execute(Object...) ...
I'm using org.graalvm.polyglot:polyglot:24.0.1, the latest version I found on the maven repository. Does anybody know how I can get this working? How can I pass functions and data to guest languages?

Did you see this in the Context javadoc? " By default only public classes, methods, and fields that are annotated with @HostAccess.Export are accessible to the guest language. This policy can be customized using Context.Builder.allowHostAccess(HostAccess) when constructing the context."
Do you use the annotation or setup host access?

What the documentation omits is 1) you need to configure your Context instance: allow the access to the host (==Java):
Context.newBuilder().allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL).build()

and 2) the stuff you're accessing must be public, including the class that declares them. Full example:
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

public class Main {
    public static class JavaRecord {
        public int x = 42;
        public double y = 42.0;
        public String name() {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder()
                .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                .build()) {
            Value record = context.asValue(new JavaRecord());
            System.out.println(record.getMember("x").asInt());
        }
    }
}

